# Can't install anything, dpkg error

Tags: installation, 10.04, apt, dpkg

I can't install anything on my Ubuntu.. I googled it, found the same problem, but none of the proposed solutions solved my issue.. All the time, it keeps giving me

```
No apport report written because the error message 
indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.  

Errors were encountered while processing:  
 tex-common  
 texlive-binaries  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I try to use `sudo apt-get install xx`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried purging tex and dependencies?

Comment: Yep, I did, didn't help..

Comment: This is an appport message, not related to the app crashing but to the system Ubuntu uses to report bugs to the developers. Please give us the full output of sudo apt-get install xx.

Comment: I don't have that now, as the problem was fixed. Sorry

Comment: @KirilKirov Would you be able to accept the other answer? As the link in your accepted one is dead now?

Comment: @Tim - Can't accept the other answer, as I don't know if it's helpful. Maybe you could ask the poster of the accepted answer, to update their post.

Comment: @KirilKirov thanks for the reply. Would you at least unaccept for the time being?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

in a terminal.

Comment: Can you tell the OP what this command does, and where to put it?